# R: gam() with smoothing splines (10-fold cross-validation, multiple predictors)

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, smoothing

Good day,

I have some difficulty writing up proper code where regression is applied to some data. I am following the book Introduction to Statistical Learning & Prediction by Trevor Hastie & Robert Tibshirani, but I can not quite follow their way of *backfitting* as how they call it.

The issue is that I want to fit a gam() with smoothing splines to my own data, I have 20 predictors and 1 response variable (y). There is no GAM comparison present, only one model will be applied to the data.

In the book, when they use **gam()** they specify degrees of freedom only for the quantitative variables in their code (they dummify the qualitative ones -- *however R does this automatically "under-the-hood" for factors right?*) :

`gam.m3 = gam( wage ∼ s( year , 4) + s( age , 5) + education , data = Wage)`

I am not sure how they computed the specific values in the book, because they are talking about *effective degrees of freedom* found by using a tuning parameter (λ) selected by cross-validation. They go through it quite fast so there isn't a lot of code that I can check, let alone one for multiple predictors (example above is from p.293)

Trial and error is getting me little, I think I understand what is needed but I can't funnel this in to R (or aRgh at the moment). In order to run the gam() correctly I need the effective degrees of freedom (obtained from optimal λ using CV), with added smoothing splines, s(), in its function.

A smoothing spline is basically a natural cubic spline at every unique level of x(i). The tuning parameter λ controls the roughness of the smoothing spline, and hence the effective degrees of freedom which I have to add in the gam(), *if I recall correctly*.

Playing around with the package (mcgv), or adding the argument `method = "GCV.Cp"` to the gam() function didn't help much. I know the smooth.splines() function has a built-in CV argument, but given that there are more predictors than one I'd like to include it in the gam() function.

Can anyone help me out on how to write up (pass gam() arguments) and find an optimal value for λ, in order to fit my GAM to the data with the found df?

**tl;dr**
`Help writing up and finding the effective degrees of freedom obtained from 10-CV (λ) for GAM (within gam() if possible or mcgv package)`

Thanks in advance.

`My code below is what I did for logistic regression with LASSO penalty for informative purposes on how I did my 10-CVs (if applicable).`

```
nFolds = 10

CVfolds = sample( rep( 1:nFolds , length=n ) , n )
cv_errors_lasso = matrix( -9999 , 1 , nFolds )

nFolds_inner = 10
for( fold in 1:nFolds )
{
  xtrain = x[ CVfolds!=fold , ] # Train is everything that isn't the fold itself
  ytrain = y[ CVfolds!=fold ]
  xtest = x[ CVfolds==fold , ] # Test is  the current fold (k) being used
  ytest = y[ CVfolds==fold ]

  cv_lasso = cv.glmnet( xtrain , ytrain , alpha = 1 , nfolds = nFolds_inner , family = c( "binomial" ) )
  cv_lasso_train = glmnet( xtrain , ytrain , alpha = 1 , lambda = cv_lasso$lambda.min )
  predict_lasso_train = predict( cv_lasso_train , xtest )
  cv_errors_lasso[ fold ] = sqrt( apply( ( ytest - predict_lasso_train )^2 , 2 , mean ) )
  print( fold )
}
```

Comment: If you do not get an answer here I would try the R-help list as i believe the author of gam monitors it.

Comment: The EDF are a function of the traces (sum of diagonal elements) of the smoothing matrices for each smooth. From `?gam` you can get these from the `nl.df` component. If you aren't wedded to `gam::gam()`, the penalized likelihood approach of Simon Wood as used in `mgcv::gam()` with automatic smoothness selection via REML/ML has a lot more going for it.

Comment: @mdewey, I am not sure on how to get there using the site's interface :(

Comment: @GavinSimpson : In the literature they specify that the function(x) should have X degrees of freedom before they run the GAM. I am wondering how they got to that number (by CV) for their variables